# Oracle Text with 'not contains' is very slow

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I have a table with million of records and Oracle Text works perfect. 

`select * from table1 where contains(col1, 'some text') > 0`

but if I add `not` it becomes very slow.

`select * from table1 where contains(col1, 'some text') > 0 and (not contains(col1, 'some text') > 0)`

or

`select * from table1 where contains(col1, 'some text') > 0 and (
contains(col1, 'some text') = 0)`

first direct query executes withing a a fraction of a second, second takes few minutes.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Try using the not operator in oracle text  (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm#CCREF0317) instead, i.e. use a single contains rather than two.

Comment: yep, that did the trick, cool! Any idea how i can use `NOT` without the first term though? I need to use `animals NOT dogs`, I would like to use just `not dogs`

Comment: I think you need to turn that around, find all documents that contain dogs and negate the result just like you did from the start. It will be slow, though.